# Flowplayer - splash screen for video container using Flashembed

Tags: javascript, json, flowplayer

Although there is plenty of information on the web regarding splash images in Flowplayer, I am having difficulty finding anything useful when using Flashembed to embed video. Here is what I have, which does not work:

```
<a href="video/myVideo.flv" style="display:block; width:280px; height:200px; padding-left:7px;" id="player"></a> 

                    <script language="JavaScript"> 
                        flashembed("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", { 

                        // "config" parameter is a complex JSON object, not just a simple value 
                        config: {
                            splash: true, 
                            clip:  { 
                                autoPlay: false, 
                                autoBuffering: true, 
                                playlist: [{url:"images/home-video-splash.jpg"}, {url: "http://myWebsite.com/video/myVideo.flv"}] 
                            } 
                        } 
                    }); 
                    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to call `flowplayer()` instead of `flashemed()` directly to see if it Works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAH! What a simple solution, rcdmk - you were right, and I also had some of my .js turned around the wrong way. So with your suggestion, and some proper syntax, which is always helpful, here is what I ended up with that now works:

```
<a href="video/myVideo.flv" style="display:block; width:280px; height:200px; padding-left:7px;" id="player"><img src="images/home-video-splash.jpg" /></a> 

                    <script language="JavaScript"> 
                        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", { 
                        // "config" parameter is a complex JSON object, not just a simple value 
                        config: { 
                            clip:  { 
                                playlist: [
                                    {
                                        url: 'images/home-video-splash.jpg'
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        url: 'http://myWebsite.com/video/myVideo.flv',
                                        autoPlay: false, 
                                        autoBuffering: true
                                    }
                                ] 
                            } 
                        }
                    }); 
                    </script>
```